# Azure release pipeline unable to read secret stored in keyvault from load test yml file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, azure-keyvault, azure-load-testing

My secret value is stored in Azure Key Vault.I have given access to key vault and load test resource. I need to send this secret in Azure Load Test yml file and run azure load tests in pipeline. When I run pipeline, it says invalid secrets. Please help how to pass this in yml file to run the test.

This is how I parameterized the HTTP request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D7dt.png)

I used getSecret function in retrieve the value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSDdQ.png)

This is how I passed them in load test yml file:

secrets: |
[
{
"name": "secretValue",
"value":  https://secret.vault.azure.net/secrets/Mysecret/45ff4094dsk9gkjdlkja5134a035uj0
}
]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is "Azure release pipeline" and I don't know what is __GetSecret() function, if your test works locally and doesn't work in the "Azure release pipeline" it means that you need to install the [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which provides this function somehow.

- If you're [installing JMeter from scratch](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) - make sure to put the .jar(s) implementing this __GetSecret() function on [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- If you're uploading your script to some form of a cloud load testing solution - it might be the case you can provide the .jar file with this __GetSecret() function along with your script